# Google Cloud SQL Mysql 5.7 minor versions, how do upgrades happen?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I have an external MySQL instance that I want to replicate to Google Cloud SQL. I have all that working, but recently we hit a very specific bug in our version (MySQL 5.7.18) which has been fixed in 5.7.21.

**Can someone explain to me how versioning and upgrades are done on Cloud SQL? Does it automatically perform upgrades of minor versions? Furthermore, which exact version of MySQL is running in Cloud SQL for MySQL 5.7?**

If Google Cloud SQL deals with all the upgrading, I'm inclined to try to force my company to move the in house database to Google Cloud since the only reason the database is in house is due to legacy and historical reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add up to the answer, as per the [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#version):

> Minor version updates are deployed as they are released, with no further action required on your part.

Also, you can track changes to Cloud SQL such as minor version upgrades in the [Release notes](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/release-notes).

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/db-versions

I think this gives me enough information

> Minor version support
>   Cloud SQL performs periodic maintenance to ensure stability and security of database instances. Maintenance includes minor version updates for each database engine. Cloud SQL determines the target minor version for each database engine, and can upgrade the target minor version at any time.
>
> When the target minor version is different than the minor version for a Cloud SQL instance, Cloud SQL will upgrade that version during the next maintenance cycle. You can control the day and time when maintenance restarts occur by setting a maintenance window for your instance.